# [Word2Vec][gensim] Handling missing words in vocabulary with the parameter min_count

Tags: python, nlp, gensim, word2vec, word-embedding

Some similar questions have been asked regarding this topic, but I am not really satisfied with the replies so far; please excuse me for that first.

I'm using the function `Word2Vec` from the python library `gensim`.

My problem is that I **can't run my model on every word of my corpus as long as I set the parameter `min_count` greater than one**. Some would say it's logic cause I choose to ignore the words appearing only once. But the function is behaving weird cause it gives an **error saying *word 'blabla' is not in the vocabulary***, whereas this is exactly what I want ( I want this word to be out of the vocabulary).

I can imagine this is not very clear, then find below a reproducible example:

```
import gensim
from gensim.models import Word2Vec

# My corpus
corpus=[["paris","not","great","city"],
       ["praha","better","great","than","paris"],
       ["praha","not","country"]]

# Load a pre-trained model - The orignal one based on google news 
model_google = gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(r'GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin', binary=True)

# Initializing our model and upgrading it with Google's 
my_model = Word2Vec(size=300, min_count=2)#with min_count=1, everything works fine
my_model.build_vocab(corpus)
total_examples = my_model.corpus_count
my_model.build_vocab([list(model_google.vocab.keys())], update=True)
my_model.intersect_word2vec_format('GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin', binary=True, lockf=1.0)
my_model.train(corpus, total_examples=total_examples, epochs=my_model.iter)

# Show examples
print(my_model['paris'][0:10])#works cause 'paris' is present twice
print(my_model['country'][0:10])#does not work cause 'country' appears only once
```

You can find Google's model [there](https://github.com/mmihaltz/word2vec-GoogleNews-vectors) for example, but feel free to use any model or just do without, this is not the point of my post.

As notified in the commentaries of the code: running the model on 'paris' works but not on 'country'. And of course, if I set the parameter `min_count` to 1, everything works fine.

I hope it is clear enough.

Thanks.

Comment: It's not clear what error your example code is getting. (The fragment of an error you show earlier, about a word `'blabla'`, doesn't match your later code.) Can you show in your question exactly what error you're getting, with the full error stack?

Comment: And, it's not clear what you'd prefer to happen. If you've chosen a parameter to discard certain words, then any attempts to access those words in the model (such as `my_model['country']`) *should* raise an error. That's correct behavior. You shouldn't try to look up known-absent (or even possibly-absent) words in the model and expect no error. (You can check if they're present beforehand, or choose to catch the potential error & adapt to the absence.)

Comment: Also note: the `.intersect_word2vec_format()` method is somewhat experimental, & never expands the vocabulary. And I don't think your `.build_vocab(…, update=True)` has any sensible effect when `min_count=2`, because every new word in `list(model_google.vocab.keys())` appears once (failing `min_count`). And more generally, adding a bunch of external words like this, but then only training your tiny subset, is not likely to be useful: training moves words to places that only make sense compared to co-trained words, making comparisons to the imported-but-untrained words possibly nonsensical.

Comment: @gojomo Thanks a lot for your reply. I'll try to answer your comments 1 by 1. 1 - just replace 'blabla' by 'country' to get the core of the error (to have the full content just run the reproducible example I shared pls, my post is already too long, haha). 2- The ultimate goal is to convert words into vectors, so If I run the model on a whole pandas column containing my words, then it will fail because some words appear only once, in this sense it's not correct. 3- I'm not sure to understand, it looks out of the topic, but I want to understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is supposed to throw an error if you ask for a word that's not present because you chose not to learn vectors for rare words, like `'country'` in your example. (And: such words with few examples usually don't get good vectors, and retaining them can worsen the vectors for remaining words, so a `min_count` as large as you can manage, and perhaps much larger than `1`, is usually a good idea.)

The fix is to do one of the following:

1. Don't ask for words that aren't present. Check first, via something like Python's `in` operator. For example:

```
if 'country' in my_model:
    print(my_model['country'][0:10])
else: 
    pass  # do nothing, since `min_count=2` means there's no 'country' vector
```

2. Catch the error, falling back to whatever you want to happen for absent words:

```
try:
    print(my_model['country'][0:10])
except:
    pass  # do nothing, or perhaps print an error, whatever
```

3. Change to using a model that always returns something for any word, like `FastText` – which will try to synthesize a vector for unknown words, using subwords learned during training. (It might be garbage, it might be pretty good if the unknown word is highly similar to known words in characters & meaning, but for some uses it's better than nothing.)

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. In the end, I did the try/except, I am just surprised this was not handled natively in the function (with a warning maybe). About your last point, do you recommend me to build my own vectors (using ```FastText``` or ```Word2Vec```, whatever) or to "mix" it with a pre-trained model that used a bigger corpus? And why?. Thanks

Comment: It *is* handled by the functions for `[]` (`__getitem__()`) and `in` (`__contains__`), You can ask whether a word-vector is present, or request a word's vector. If you request a word that's absent, this is handled natively in the supporting code by running `raise KeyError()` – see https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/68ec5b8ed7f18e75e0b13689f4da53405ef3ed96/gensim/models/keyedvectors.py#L276. The only other option would be to return a flag value meaning 'absent', which would require just as much extra checking/branching code by you, the caller, to do the right thing for your needs.

Comment: Train your own vectors, using a sufficient number and variety of texts that demonstrate word usage in your problem domain, if at all possible. Word-vectors imported from elsewhere may not emphasize the word-interrelationships as they exist in your domain, and to import-then-train-only-some-words, as you've attempted, risks pulling the words getting continuing training out of compatible alignment with unadjusted import words.

Comment: Thanks again. FYI, I've tried 3 approaches: training my own vectors, using an external model (famous Google's one) and what I've shown you. The 2 last approaches get more or less the same results (I'm doing a binary classification) and the first one gets really bad results (probably because the corpus is small - ~7k tweets)

Comment: 7k tweets might only be, what, 140k words? Yes, that's way too small to train a useful word2vec model. But there are far more than 7k tweets in the world, so finding 7 million or 70 million tweets (or tweet-like utterances with similar language usage) to train your word-vectors shouldn't be impossible.